# Import Error from angular.json in Angular 12

Tags: angular

Im upgrading my project from Angular 10 to 12. 10 -> 11 worked fine.
When compiling version 12, I got this error:

```
Error: Should not import the named export 'projects' (imported as 'angular_constants') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
```

In some component, I used this import:

```
import * as angular_constants                   from "../../angular.json";
[...]
var all_keys = Object.keys(angular_constants.projects);
this.project_labels = all_keys[0];
```

With this code, I used to access the angular.json keys and values. It allow me to access Project Name (test_project in this example) without manually write the name in every component I need it.

```
"projects": {
    "test_project": {      
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
```

It seems Angular 12 doesn't allow this tricky import anymore or I cant figure out how to make it works.

UPDATE: 2021-08-31

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "es2020", 
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

in the root level of your `tsconfig` file and also add `"resolveJsonModule": true` under `compilerOptions` if you don't have it already there.

Comment: I've added the options as you said but it still wont works. You can see my current tsconfig above.

Comment: `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` this should be outside compilerOptions, on root level of your file
`{
  "compileOnSave": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true,
  "compilerOptions": {...`